# How can I recognize digits from photo (.jpg format) using Python and TF, Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I used OpenCV to crop images from the photo. 
From this:
[image]

to this :
[image]

Then I crop it to 5 different parts with different types of threshold and angle (in rotation matrix 2D) for training a neural network.
Now I have 45 similar jpg files for any digits from 0 to 9.
But I can't understand how could I train it with my own data, not using MNIST datasets
Help me out to dealing with building a digit recognition program, please. I need to extract all the digits from img to text.

Comment: Your input is the whole image? or you want to recognize the extracted digits? i.e. Recognition and classification? or just classification.

Comment: @Dinari, in general, I need the whole line, but to make it easy I cropped it into 5 separate parts
So, I made 45 of each digit to train a neural network for it to better recognition, but I can't deal with the sclearn

Comment: Did you explore existing OCR solutions? such as pytesseract?  45 samples of each digit are not alot.

Comment: @Dinari, yup, that was the first thing I did, but no matter how I tried to get rid of noise, it won't recognise a thing

Comment: Hi, i have the same problem, have you solve your problem?? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are going for the NN approach, I would first start with a small nn, and see how well it does, you can use the MNIST toy example from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/).

Just note that you will need to use your own data, instead of mnist:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x_train, y_train = load_train_data()
x_test, y_test = load_test_data()


model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Note that I 'invented' 2 functions: `load_train_data()` and `load_test_data()`, you need to implement them for your data, and return a tuple, of `((samples,x,y), labels)`, for each one of the functions.

Once you get the feeling, I would explore a bit more advanced networks, you can look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-2d-cnn-for-mnist-digit-recognition-a998dbc1e79a, its a nice tutorial for 2d CNN network, just use your data loading functions instead of the mnist. 
As you will now probably face a wall, as you don't have enough data, you need to apply some data augmentation. 
There is a very nice solution '[Deep Diffeomorphic Transformer Networks](http://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_cvpr_2018/papers_backup/Detlefsen_Deep_Diffeomorphic_Transformer_CVPR_2018_paper.pdf)' from the last CVPR, performs very well on digits classification with a low amount of samples. You can find the mnist code [here](https://github.com/SkafteNicki/ddtn/blob/master/ddtn/mnist_classifier.py), again use your functions for the data.